# Algebraicity of a proper holomorphic map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a proper holomorphic map between complex analytic spaces. Suppose that $Y\subset \Bbb{P}^n$ is a closed analytic subset. By Chow's theorem, $Y$ is a projective algebraic variety and $f_*O_X$ is a coherent algebraic sheaf (Grauert direct image theorem+GAGA). Is $X$ algebraic? Does $f$ comes from a morphism of algebraic varieties?

Comment: Presumably one ought to enforce some nontriviality conditions here - taking $Y$ to be a point and $X$ to be any proper non-algebraic complex analytic space produces a (potentially silly) counterexample.

Comment: As properness is not sufficient (pointed out by @KReiser), a replacement could be finiteness of $f$. See Appendix B, Theorem 3.2 of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry.